# Display InfoView React Google Maps

Tags: reactjs, google-maps, maps, marker, infowindow

I have a problem with my code.
I want to display InfoWindow when I click on a marker but actually all markers open automatically (also if *showInfo* attribute is set to false) and not when i click on each of them.

There is the return method because I need to put all this code in render method of my component.

```
const markers = this.props.markers.map((venue, i) => {

        const marker = {

            showInfo: false,

            position: {
                lat: venue.location.lat,
                lng: venue.location.lng
            },

            name: venue.name,

            handleMarkerTap(marker) {

                if (marker.showInfo === false) {
                    marker.showInfo = true
                } else if (marker.showInfo === true) {
                    marker.showInfo = false
                }

                console.log(marker.showInfo);
            }
        };


        return(

            <Marker key={i} onClick={marker.handleMarkerTap(marker)} {...marker} >

                {marker.showInfo && (

                    <InfoWindow
                        onCloseClick={marker.handleMarkerTap(marker)} >

                            <div>
                                <b>{marker.name}</b>
                            </div>


                    </InfoWindow>
                )}

            </Marker>
        )
    });
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you filtering which marker infowindow to toggle with id? You need to do something like this.

```
  onToggleInfo = id => {
    const new_locations = this.state.locations.map(
      location =>
        id === location.id
          ? { ...location, info_open: !location.info_open }
          : { ...location, info_open: false }
    );
    this.setState({ locations: new_locations });
  };
```

Comment: No, I don't know where to do it. could you help me? Thank you.. Can I give you my email address

Comment: I saw your entire code. You are getting closer! The problem is, I don't think you are passing the targetMarker properly. Try console.logging targetMarker. In case, here is mine (https://github.com/Tetsuya3850/MERN-Sprint/tree/master/gmap/client/src)

Comment: To access the targetMarker I once used ref (https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html) but I think the id approach is simpler.

Comment: Has the issue solved? If so, please indicate that this question is okay by accepting.

Comment: Great! How to indicate that an answer is solved is here (https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147531/how-mark-my-question-as-answered-on-stackoverflow) Um, sure but I think that's not how things work here. You could post that question as a new one at Stack Overflow. Not personal chats!